# I want to write an article on Universal Usability

Tags: usability, user-expectation, users

I want to write an article on Universal Usability. What are the aspects shall I cover ? Any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However, I did not research on this topic, following is the paper of MIT on this very topic.

[link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj0iuG-04jsAhVYIbcAHW6-DW4QFjAJegQIAxAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fweb.mit.edu%2F16.459%2Fwww%2FUnivUsab.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0NbWXxzisEjgo2ubSlIxQ-)

This paper mentions following areas to be considered:

1. Equitable Use
2. Flexibility in use
3. Simple and Intuitive
4. Perceptible Information
5. Tolerance for Error
6. Low Physical Effort
7. Size and Space for Approach and use

The content is very informative and with examples.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Try Googling "Universal Design"